# Unused write database connections

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, scalability

This issue was raised using Laravel 5.0.

My project's database setup consists of 1 write node and multiple read-replicas (postgresql). Everytime a connection is initiated for any query, eg:

`php
<?php $user = \App\User::find(1); ?>`

... a connection is made to the write node. This occurs even when no writing queries are run (including `set names 'utf8'`, etc); a connection will be set up, but all the `SELECT` queries are run correctly on the read-replicas.

How can I avoid this write connection if I don't need/use it for read-only requests?

Comment: You mentioned that you are using fideloper technique of 2 connection, but how do you actively switch between a Read/Write? ie when you hit `->save()` how is the model grabbing mysql2 and not 1

Comment: @azngunit81 You'd have to explicitly call [setConnection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3272-L3283) on the model prior to saving it.

Comment: awww, thats dirty to explicitly do that

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes maintaining the DB connections: `Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager` and `Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory`.

When any Laravel class want to use a DB connection, it makes a call to `DatabaseManager::connection()`, which eventually request for an actual connection via `ConnectionFactory::make()`.

Your issue lies here, the underlying of `make()` process creates both 'read' and 'write' connections at the same time. So 'write' connection is always established. It is a behavior of `ConnectionFactory`.

So the best way is opening an issue on Laravel asking the dev team whether they would like to improve the connection establishment only when it is actually needed.

**Edited:**

I just found that you already opened an issue :-)

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10337

Comment: Yep! I opened an issue. In the meantime, I'm using the techniques described in [http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections), coupled with dynamically generated config to decide which read node is used per request.